# OpenLDAP overlay memberof only returns first member

Tags: openldap, memberof

I just installed OpenLdap 2.4.44 with the overlay memberOf. I configured the overlay to use uniquemember and groupOfUniqueNames for the attribute

```
overlay memberof
memberof-group-oc groupOfUniqueNames
memberof-member-ad uniquemember
```

The problem is that the attribute memberOf seems to only be applied to the first entry of the group. If I have a group with more than one uniqueMember, only the first one is returned when I do a query by memberOf. And if I try to get the attribute memberOf for any other entry, it returns empty, like it does not belong to the group. Any idea?

Comment: Not true. Post your code. In your question.

Comment: Well, it is true, but I just discovered why. I'm importing the data from an existing LDIF, and it seems the group entries in the LDIF failed are created just after the first member of the group. So when the group is created, only the first member exists, so the relationshp for the attribute memberOf is only created for the first one.

Comment: No, it isn't true. I have code that has been running for seven years that shows it isn't true. Yyou don't have any data that would exhibit it if it was. There was never a problem of this nature to solve.

Comment: Let me rephrase. There was no problem with the overlay. There was a problem with the data I loaded, because the groups(with all the uniqueMembers) were imported before the users, so the attribute memberOf did not work for the those users imported after the creation of the group. I modified the load to create the groups at the end, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was actually a silly thing, but in case somebody has the same issue in the future, I posted the solution here. It wasn't a problem with OpenLdap but with the data import. The load was done from an existing LDIF file. For some reason the order of the file was something like this:

```
dn: cn=Employee1, cn=employees, dc=dev, dc=company,dc=com
cn=Employee1
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson

dn: cn=Employees,cn=groups,dc=dev, dc=company,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniqueMember: cn=Employee1, cn=employees, dc=dev, dc=company,dc=com
uniqueMember: cn=Employee2, cn=employees, dc=dev, dc=company,dc=com
uniqueMember: cn=Employee3, cn=employees, dc=dev, dc=company,dc=com
cn: Employees

dn: cn=Employee2, cn=employees, dc=dev, dc=company,dc=com
cn=Employee2
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson

dn: cn=Employee3, cn=employees, dc=dev, dc=company,dc=com
cn=Employee3
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
```

So only the first entry existed before the group with the references to all entries was imported, and memberOf worked for that first entry, but not for the entries imported later.